# API Keys with dotenv made me net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, environment-variables, dotenv

Im trying so hard to run this "[job project](https://github.com/codebubb/job-search-app)" from Github, so i put my API keys on `.env` created file locate on root of api directory

```
APP_ID=00000000
API_KEY=000000000000000000000000
```

...and put this code on my `config.js` :

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'api/.env' })
module.exports = {
  APP_ID: process.env.APP_ID,
  API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY,
  BASE_URL: 'https://api.adzuna.com/v1/api/jobs',
  BASE_PARAMS: 'search/1?&results_per_page=20&content- 
  type=application/json',
};
```

But it looks like the request failing with this error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED:
[image]
I think, it dosent happens to take the api keys values, because `accessKeyId` is always empty

So, does there any other way to hide the api keys for it to work ?

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you console log process.env.API_KEY ?

Comment: @aroundtheworld i tried to type  ```console.log(process.env)``` on my config.js file but it dosent recognize that

Comment: Ok, is your server running successfully? When you start the server do any messages appear in the terminal?

Comment: yeah i have this : > frontend@1.0.0 dev
> parcel index.html

Server running at http://localhost:1234
✨ Built in 1.24s

Comment: Thanks, and it is making a call to `localhost:3000` from your screenshot - so is that a server you are running locally?

Comment: Yes is running on local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240906/discussion-between-noob-dev95-and-aroundtheworld).

Comment: It is not in the spirit of StackOverflow to chat privately. We are here to solve this publicly for others to learn from. I believe your server has some issue running, which may or may not relate to your .env variable file. Without more information I am not sure I can help further